# Time spent on a stack of a NavigationStack

Tags: swiftui

I would like to measure the time I spend on a stack of a `NavigationStack` and its children. I have tried to launch a timer inside a `.onAppear()` call of the stack view and stop it on an `.onDisappear()` call of the same View. But it only gives me the time I spent on the specific stack whereas I want to get the time I spend on this stack and its substacks.

Any solution on how to do that?

Comment: Show the code. You probably don't need timer at all

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by observing the `path` property of the `NavigationStack`. Associate each view in the stack with a unique identifier and then just check if the view you're interested in exists in the path. Start and stop the timer based on the existence of that value in the path. A quick example on how to achieve this would be:

*(When `View2` is present on the stack the timer starts and when it is removed from the stack the timer stops)*

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var path = [String]()
    @State var timeSpent = 0
    
    @State var timerCancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(path.description)
            
            Text(timeSpent.description)
            
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                VStack {
                    Text("This is the Root View")
                    NavigationLink("Show View 1", value: "1")
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { id in
                    // here we associate each view with an "id"
                    switch id {
                    case "1": View1()
                    case "2": View2()
                    case "2.1": View2_1()
                    case "2.2": View2_2()
                    default: Text("Unknown path")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: path) {
                // here we add the logic to start/stop the timer
                if path.contains("2") {
                    guard timerCancellable == nil else { return }
                    timeSpent = 0
                    timerCancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
                        .autoconnect()
                        .sink { date in
                            timeSpent += 1
                        }
                } else {
                    timerCancellable = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is View 1")
            NavigationLink("Show View 2", value: "2")
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is View 2")
            NavigationLink("Show View 2.1", value: "2.1")
            NavigationLink("Show View 2.2", value: "2.2")
        }
    }
}

struct View2_1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2.1")
    }
}

struct View2_2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2.2")
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, perhaps using enums or `Identifiable`, but this should get you started in the right direction. Best of luck!